# Error al correr mi app Ionic 3

Tags: ionic, cordova

He creado una app de ionic 3 completamente nueva, con esto digo que no he hecho nada en la misma. Al correr en mi consola: cordova run android recibo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando ionic 3. Alguien me puede ayudar ?

Comment: Has comprobado que los directorios mostrados sean correctos y existan?

Comment: si estan en el lugar correcto

Comment: Si te está diciendo q las rutas del JDK o SDK q especificase no las encuentra

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner comillas en el JAVA_HOME? (Algo como `JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_131"`) Como _Program Files_ tiene un espacio, quizás ese sea el problema (el sistema operativo podría considerar que el path es `C:\Program`, que no existe)

Comment: Solucionado gracias solo reinstalle todod y ya me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Para Ionic con Android , hay que instalar :

1. JDK de java
2. Instala Android Studio y descargas las versiones de android que te interesan.
3. Crea la maquina virtual del dispositivo desde el Android Studio y lo ejecutas , desde Ionic.